# VIP stuck in the back of a van? (Council Extraction Mission)

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

During a small enemy engagement a nearby van was destroyed and some of its walls - leaving it now accessible. Problem is that during this enemy encounter my VIP panicked and ran into the back of this van...problem is that now he's stuck and can't get out.

[image: XCOM VIP stuck in a van]

Does anyone know of a method by which I can get him down from his elevated position?

TBH it does seem pretty ridiculous that a VIP can't even get down from a van...anyhow I've killed all hostiles *(at great expense of life)* so I really don't want to lose this VIP over something as silly as this.

Comment: Have you tried moving the heavy out of the way?

Comment: If that doesn't work, is there an old enough autosave you can load?

Comment: try to scroll the mousewheel a bit to have a look at other planes, maybe this will help..

Comment: I just moved the heavy in there in the desperate hope it might bring up the option, "Throw VIP out of the Bloody Truck", funnily enough it didn't... I've also tried looking at different levels, still no luck and I don't have an autosave either so my only real option is to abort and quit :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. It has been experienced by other players in [these](http://forums.2k.com/showthread.php?170786-BUG-Units-stuck-on-the-cargo-area-of-a-Van) [threads](http://steamcommunity.com/app/200510/discussions/0/864949037849708320/) in the 2K and Steam community forums (the threads appear to be started by the same player, but in a reply on the Steam thread a second player confirms experiencing it too). The only resolution of the situation mentioned in the threads is to have the units effected killed by aliens, which is hardly ideal.

The threads are from 2012 but I see no mention of it made in any of the [patch notes](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Patch_%26_Update_(XCOM:_Enemy_Unknown)) I could find, I assume it may still be an issue.

Comment: Well as I said...I killed all the aliens. I started a new game anyway so I'm not too bothered anymore! Hopefully it gets fixed soon though.

Comment: This is a bug that has been discussed on reddit's XCOM page. It's annoying, and yes, you will have to reload a save.